# Ansible: How to execute a lookup plugin from an action plugin

Tags: ansible

I'm developing an action plugin. I'd like to run a lookup plugin from inside the code of the action plugin.

Was wondering if as much is possible, and if so - how to do it? (Something similar to `self._execute_module()` I presume?) I don't see anything in the [ActionBase code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py) that hints at how this could be done.

Comment: I don't believe plugins have any ability to "call back" into ansible, since they're run in a spawned copy of python just for their execution, so anything you wish to have provided via a lookup should be passed in by the user as a parameter to your task

Comment: action plugins do just that - they run on the control node and usually make calls to modules (which are run - possibly remotely - in spawned pythons). Figured lookups could be used in the same way. Currently i just made a module that does the same thing as the lookup and the plugin uses that, but using the lookup directly would save code duplication.